# What are the lyrics to two songs covered by a 1998 Rock-n-Roll Elmo?

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, cover

I used to own one of these toys when I was really little, but I always had trouble understanding the words because of my hearing loss.

The [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKa7qN75lRE) song by the Elmo doll is a cover of Jackson 5's *ABC*. It seems that the doll's lyrics are different than the original song and would better match these [kids cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8m7yhtPsqc).

Does someone have the lyrics of this cover?

There was another [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIWHgqwcEaI) song by the same doll I couldn't identify, so if background information and lyrics can be provided that would be excellent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96019/discussion-between-heavenlyharmony-and-bebs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first song is just the chorus to the original *ABC* by the Jackson 5, repeated twice with the name "Elmo" inserted instead of "baby"

> Ba-ba-ba-ba!
>   A B C, easy as one, two, three
>   Simple as do re mi
>   A B C, one, two, three, Elmo, you and [unintelligible]

The second song is Big Joe Turner's *Shake Rattle and Roll*

> Check it out!
>
> Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
>   Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
>   Get in that kitchen, make some noise with the pots and pans
>
> Shake rattle & roll!
>   Gonna shake rattle & roll!
>   Gonna shake rattle & roll!
>   [unintelligible] rock and roll

There are some minor lyric changes to both songs, but nothing significant.

Answer (score 0):

he first song is just the chorus to the original ABC by the Jackson 5, repeated twice with the name "Elmo" inserted instead of "baby"

```
Sing with elmo! 

Ba-ba-ba-ba!
A B C, easy as one, two, three
Simple as do re mi
A B C, one, two, three, Elmo, you and [unintelligible]
```

The second song is Big Joe Turner's Shake Rattle and Roll

```
Check it out!

Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
Get in that kitchen, make some noise with the pots and pans

Shake rattle & roll!
Gonna shake rattle & roll! Gonna shake rattle & roll!
Elmo plays the guitar and sing and rock and roll

ba ba ab ab pow,
Yeah!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The first song you're talking about goes:

> Ba-ba-ba-ba!
> A B C, easy as one, two, three
> Simple as do re mi
> A B C, one, two, three, Elmo, you and [unintelligible]

And the second song goes:

> Check it out!

> Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
> Get out of that bed, wash your face and hands
> Get in that kitchen, make some noise with the pots and pans

> Shake rattle & roll!
> Gonna shake rattle & roll!
> Gonna shake rattle & roll!
> [unintelligible] rock and roll